# GREP to find and change after a number in InDesign

Tags: grep, adobe-indesign, grep-indesign

Is there a grep to find and change after a number input a force line break?

I have some like this

```
"1651651 John Doe"
```

The number is variable , and the name too.

I want to do that

```
"1651651

John Doe"
```

Comment: "grep" does not modify files. It only searches them. Maybe you want a `sed` or `awk` script?

Comment: Are you trying to do this with GREP styles or a search and replace?

Answer (score 1):

With GREP you can find a some variable. Say, a 'custom text variable' `~u`. But it will be any 'custom text variable'. GREP tool can't tell if the variable contains the number of the name.

Or, if you sure that the first variable is a number and second one is a name always, you can use something like this:

Find what: `(~u) (~u)`

Replace to: `($1)\n\n($2)`

Probably the task can be accomplished with a script. It depends on what exactly you have and what you want to get.